# Migrate XP Windows Explorer folder links/shortcuts to Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

In windows xp with IE7, you could create favorites for both URLs and file folders. I have exported/imported my IE URL favorites to IE8 on windows 7. That's great, but the file folders didn't get migrated.

How do I move the file folder favorites to Windows 7 (favorites or library)?

I tried to simply copy the favorites folder to Windows 7 and add it to a library. The folder links are *.lnk files, which Windows 7 doesn't seem to recognize. So, that appears to be a dead-end. Perhaps a converter for *.lnk to Windows 7 library entries or favorites?

Suggestions welcome.

Comment: Are you sure they aren't .url files?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't really know how to do *import* your old Favorites, but a workaround might be to add any site (it doesn't matter which) to your Favorites, and then edit the properties of that Favorite.  For instance, make a Favorite of [Google](http://www.google.com), and then right-click on it to edit its properties.  You'd change the name (on the "General" tab of the properties window) to be something like "C-Drive" and then change the address to "C:\" (on the "Web Document" tab of the properties window; also, the path should be auto-corrected to "file:///c:/" when you click "Apply").

This works for me!  Now when I click on that Favorite, the C:\ opens right up!